# How many integers in the range satisfy a given congruence?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Specifically how many integers $x$ in the range $1 ≤ x ≤ 60$ satisfy $21x ≡ 24\ (mod\ 60)$? And how many integers $a$ are there in the range $1 ≤ a ≤ 74$ for which the equation $x^2 ≡ a\ (mod\ 37)$ is soluble?

I have the solutions to be $3$ and $38$ respectively but not too sure how they came up with those answers.

For the first one, I believe it's because $21x ≡ 24\ (mod\ 60) \implies 3\cdot7x \equiv 3\cdot8\ (mod\ 60) \implies 7\cdot8x\ (mod\ 20) \implies x \equiv 4\ (mod\ 20)$
Then looking in the range from $1\ to\ 60$, $60/20 = 3$ to give us 3 integers.

Not sure about the second..

Comment: For the second, note that $x^2\equiv a+37\pmod{37}$ is soluble iff $x^2\equiv a\pmod37$ is. So there are twice as many $a$ in the range $1\le a\le 74$ as in $1\le a\le 37$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second one, it's basically asking how many quadratic residues are in $Z_{37}$. Since 37 is prime, there must be exactly $\frac{p-1}{2}$ residues and non-residues in the range from $1-36$, now, 37 is a trivial residue, so you would get $18+1=19$ residues in the range $1\leq a\leq37$ As we are in modulo 37, the range $38\leq a \leq74$ behaves similarly as $1\leq a\leq37$. So  you would get $19*2=38$ residues in total.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
   21x &\equiv 24 \pmod{60} \\
   7x &\equiv 8 \pmod{20} \\
   x &\equiv 4 \pmod{20} \\
   x &\in \{4, 24, 44 \}
\end{align}

TOTAL = 3

---

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
x & x^2 \pmod{37}\\
\hline
 0,37 &  0 \\
 1,36 &  1 \\
 2,35 &  4 \\
 3,34 &  9 \\
 4,33 & 16 \\
 5,32 & 25 \\
 6,31 & 36 \\
 7,30 & 12 \\
 8,29 & 27 \\
 9,28 &  7 \\
10,27 & 26 \\
11,26 & 10 \\
12,25 & 33 \\
13,24 & 21 \\
14,23 & 11 \\
15,22 &  3 \\
16,21 & 34 \\
17,20 & 30 \\
18,19 & 28 \\
\hline 
\end{array}

TOTAL = $2 \times 19 = 38$